# Proof of lifting the exponent lemma

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I recently read about the lifting the exponent lemma in a handout I understood most part of it but couldnt understand the proof from where n(exponent of the numbers) was assumed as $p^ab$ p and b coprime with p (prime) any help to make me understand it would be great.Thanks in advance.
https://brilliant.org/wiki/lifting-the-exponent/
Proof of lemma step 2

Comment: Can you please link, or better yet include in the body of your question, the particular step you had trouble with? Some proofs of this lemma might be structured in different ways, and I can't tell exactly what argument you're asking about.

Answer (score 1):

Given $n$ and $p$, we can define $k$ to be $v_p(n)$. Then $p^k$ divides $n$, and so $n$ can be written as $n=p^ka$ for some integer $a$. We know
$$k=v_p(n)=v_p(p^ka)=v_p(p^k)+v_p(a)=k+v_p(a),$$
so $v_p(a)=0$, and so $p$ cannot divide $a$.

Comment: Thanks but can you plz explain what is done in step 2 of the proof on the link i sent(last few lines of the proof)

Comment: @Mathenthusiast What other parts of the logic of step 2 do you not understand?

Comment: Why is V(x^p^k-y^p^k)=V(x^p^k-1-y^p^k-1)+1

Comment: @Mathenthusiast It's using step 1 on the pair $(x^{p^{k-1}},y^{p^{k-1}})$.